# Why "of" is not JavaScript keyword?

Tags: javascript

What does "of" represent in the loop statement for...of?

I can assign a value to it

```
const of = "text";
```

whereas an analogy with "in" from for...in loop

```
const in = "text";
```

is not possible.

Why "of" is not one of reserved words?

Comment: Most likely backwards compatability concerns.

Comment: `in` and `of` ARE `keywords`, however `of` seems to be assignable, as you say.

Comment: Nice question. You can have `of` variable name because `of` is not a reserved word [in ES standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-ReservedWord). Why it is not reserved word, I don't know..

Comment: `in` can appear not only in the for loop, but e.g. also in a condition like `"a" in {a:1,b:2}`. Does `of` has similar other usage then in a `for of` loop?

Comment: It might not be a reserved word, but I'd definitely call it a keyword in a `for` loop.

Comment: For the same reason that `let` is not a reserved word (try `var let = 1`): backward compatibility with scripts written before it was introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`of` is not a reserved word according to the [ECMAScript standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-ReservedWord).

This may be due to the fact that some browsers don't comply to standards, and some do. If the spec added `of` as a keyword, sites that declared a variable named `of` might break completely. The Javascript spec has to be backwards-compatible for the web to not break.

To quote @Bergi in the comments,

> Rather, the other way round: the spec is written so that browsers that stay backwards-compatible can comply to it. If the ECMAScript 2020 language had been designed today, it definitely would have been made a reserved word.

Comment: Rather, the other way round: the spec is written so that browsers that stay backwards-compatible can comply to it. If the ECMAScript 2020 language had been designed today, it definitely would have been made a reserved word.